# Vector Picking on the Unit Sphere

Tags: random-variables, 3d, vector-analysis, spherical-geometry, spherical-coordinates

Imagine a vector from the center of a unit sphere to its surface:
[image]
Now imagine a second vector generated in indentical fashion.  Given the first vector, how can I generate vectors to uniformally distribute the angle between them (`θ`).

My first thought was to use spherical coordinates -- however this generates a non-uniform distribution (as most points picked will be near the equatorial circumference, relative to the first vector):
[image: Angle distribution]

Next I read this [Wolfram Alpha article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html) on sphere point picking.  But that yields nearly identical results... the {X,Y,Z} endpoint is now uniformally distributed, but the angle (`θ`) between the two unit vectors is not.

The closest I've come is to pick the end point of the second vector on a unit circle which I place in plane centered on the sphere's center point.  Then I take the point and rotate about the original vector by a random amount using the [equation for rotation about a line in arbitrary space](http://inside.mines.edu/~gmurray/ArbitraryAxisRotation/) (such that the unit sphere's center can be place in arbitrary space).

This gives this distribution:
[image]
Which is relatively flat on [30,150], but spikes near the peaks.

Any ideas on how to pick the second vector so as to give a uniform angular distribution?

Comment: Just to be clear: you're well aware that uniform angular distribution does _not_ correspond to any uniform distribution on the sphere, and you're certain that uniform angular distribution is the correct notion of uniformity for your application?

Comment: Yes, that is the case.  The application is dependent on using pseudo-random uniform draws of angles for a dependent formula to drive a Markov chain.  And yes, as I show above, both trival (non-uniform) rectangular coordinate distribution and more advanced uniform rectangular coord. distributions fail to uniformally distribute the angles (as you state).  The question is how to get such a uniform distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In spherical coordinates, the surface area of a sphere is proportional to (1 minus the cosine of the polar angle), as measured from a chosen "pole" on the sphere.  So perhaps after choosing your first vector, the second vector would be chosen so that $ \ -1 \  \le  \cos \theta  \le  +1 \ $ is uniformly distributed for your second vector, $ \ \theta \ $ being the plane angle between them, and the "azimuthal angle" $ \ 0 \le  \phi < 2 \pi\ $ for the direction of the second vector being uniformly distributed.

Comment: Sounds promising, but how do you suggest ensuring the planar angle is uniformally distributed?  I'm a bit confused because it seemed like you reiterated by question... maybe I'm missing your train of thought.

Comment: What I'm proposing is that the point on the sphere's surface for the first vector is used to define a "North Pole", from which polar angle $ \ \theta \ $ is measured.  The value of $ \ \cos \theta \ $ is what would be used as the uniform random variable.  That leaves a circle parallel to the "Equator" that the second vector could now point anywhere along; that vector could point at any azimuthal angle $ \ \phi \ $ on the circle , though that isn't central to the arrangement I think you are asking about, since the angle $ \ \theta \  $ is the same for all of those choices.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand... let me test this....

Comment: What if you start _from_ spherical coordinates (really only the two angular ones, since we are on a unit sphere) and then transform $ \ \theta \ $ and $ \ \phi \ $ into rectangular coordinates?

Comment: That's what generated the first distribution... :(  All of the approaches appear to be non-uniform in the same way for theta (due to the equator problem), while some are uniform for (X,Y,Z) on the shell, others are not.  I think you're right -- I need to draw cosθ and then solve for the second vector using the law of cosines... but I think this will require some sort of quadratic solving code which looks nasty.

Comment: I think that's what's going on in the sample code I was asking about in the other question I posted:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410338/sample-code-to-generate-points-on-the-rim-of-a-randomly-rotated-cone-whats-go

Comment: Okay, so the code I linked definitely produces a flat distribution and I believe that it essentially follows your solution.  I want to understand the math though, and I'm struggling with how to get from your suggestion (using the law of cosines) to the end point code... can you take a look @ that code and see if you can explain what the steps taken are?  If you can explain it I'll give you credit for answering both questions. :)

Comment: @JasonR.Mick I don't recognize the coding language, but from what I could puzzle out about its grammar, I don't think it is doing what I've been describing.  It seems to be based entirely in an approach using rectangular coordinates (which may be complicating what the programmer wants to do), but the process seems to have a different intent from what we've been discussing on this page.

Comment: Okay I returned to my original code (which essentially did what you said and was generating that bottom distribution)... I found a bug in the part that was generating the normal... once I fixed that the distribution was flat!! :)

Comment: @JasonR.Mick  Hooray!  Glad to hear this worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I have misunderstood, this problem does not have a unique solution, perhaps you have to be more specific. One solution is this: Without loss of generality, suppose the original vector is on the equator. Then, you just uniformly pick vectors on the equator, and there you go (For $2$ dimensions uniform point picking will yield a uniform angle distribution.).